# PHP: How to encode infinity or NaN numbers to JSON?

Tags: php, json, nan, infinity

Apparently, infinity and NaN are not a part of JSON specification, so this PHP code:

```
$numbers = array();
$numbers ['positive_infinity'] = +INF;
$numbers ['negative_infinity'] = -INF;
$numbers ['not_a_number'] = NAN;
$array_print = print_r ($numbers, true);
$array_json = json_encode ($numbers);
echo "\nprint_r(): $array_print";
echo "\njson_encode(): $array_json";
```

Produces this:

```
PHP Warning:  json_encode(): double INF does not conform to the JSON spec, encoded as 0 in /home/septi/test.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  json_encode(): double -INF does not conform to the JSON spec, encoded as 0 in /home/septi/test.php on line 8
PHP Warning:  json_encode(): double NAN does not conform to the JSON spec, encoded as 0 in /home/septi/test.php on line 8

print_r(): Array
(
    [positive_infinity] => INF
    [negative_infinity] => -INF
    [not_a_number] => NAN
)

json_encode(): {"positive_infinity":0,"negative_infinity":0,"not_a_number":0}
```

Is there any way to correctly encode these numbers without writing my own `json_encode()` function? Maybe some workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to JSON spec, there is no Infinity or NaN values: http://json.org/

Workarounds:

1. Reject using JSON (pure JSON), and write your own json_encode function, which will handle INF/NAN (converting to "Infinity" and "NaN" respectively), and make sure you are parsing JSON using something like `result = eval('(' + json + ')');` on the client side.
2. Pre convert your IFN/NAN values into string values ('Infinity' and 'NaN'), and when you are going to operate with those values in JavaScript, use the following construction: `var number1 = (+numbers.positive_infinity);`. This will convert string value 'Infinity' into numeric `Infinity` representation.

Comment: You could additionally use `JSON.stringify(json, replacer)`, where `replacer` is some function that replaces `Infinity`, `NaN`, etc. into their string representations (see https://levelup.gitconnected.com/manipulating-json-strings-in-javascript-5c9423841fa3 for an example)

Answer (score 14):

You are right about the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> Numeric values that cannot be represented as sequences of digits (such as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted.

The solution must also come from the spec, since a custom "JSON" encoder would not produce valid JSON anyway (you would have to write a custom decoder as well, and then you and consumers of your data would be forced to use that until the end of time).

Here' what the spec allows for values:

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names:
>
> ```
> false null true
> ```

So, any workaround that involves legal JSON instead of a custom JSON-like protocol would involve using something else instead of numbers.

One reasonable option would be to use the strings `"Infinity"` and `"NaN"` for these edge cases.

Comment: +1 for citing the spec and mentioning literals. Accepting the other answer, however, because it suggests the way to convert them back to numbers.

Answer (score 11):

This is in my opinion a big shortcoming of JSON. Different JSON encoders handle this differently, a quick overview can be found here: http://lavag.org/topic/16217-cr-json-labview/?p=99058

One solution is to encode +inf as +1e9999 as that will naturally overflow to +inf in most decoders, and same with -inf as -1e9999. NaN is much harder.

Answer (score 3):

As an update to readers of this question for newer versions of PHP >= 5.5.0, to get `INF` or `NAN` values from `json_encode` to be encoded as `0` rather than `json_encode` failing to output at all, add the [JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)  option.

As an example: `json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);`

Answer (score 0):

The warning mentioned above, there is official bug reported in php documentation.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64695