# How to parse JSON string containing "NaN" in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, gson

Have a node.js app that is receiving JSON data strings that contain the literal NaN, like

```
 "[1, 2, 3, NaN, 5, 6]"
```

This crashes `JSON.parse(...)` in Node.js.  I'd like to parse it, if i can into an object.

I know `NaN` is not part of JSON spec.  Most SO links ([sending NaN in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601812/sending-nan-in-json)) suggest to fix the output.

Here, though the data is produced in a server I don't control, it's by a commercial Java library where I can see the source code.   And it's produced by Google's Gson library:

```
private Gson gson = (new GsonBuilder().serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues().create()); 
... 
gson.toJson(data[i], Vector.class, jsonOut)
```

So that seems like a legitimate source.  And according to the [Gson API Javadoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues%28%29) it says I should be able to parse it:

> Section 2.4 of JSON specification disallows special double values
>   (NaN, Infinity, -Infinity). However, Javascript specification (see
>   section 4.3.20, 4.3.22, 4.3.23) allows these values as valid
>   Javascript values. Moreover, most JavaScript engines will accept these
>   special values in JSON without problem. So, at a practical level, it
>   makes sense to accept these values as valid JSON even though JSON
>   specification disallows them.

Despite that, this fails in both Node.js and Chrome:  `JSON.parse('[1,2,3,NaN,"5"]')`

**Is there a flag to set in JSON.parse()?  Or an alternative parser that accepts `NaN` as a literal?**

I've been Googling for a while but can't seem to find a doc on this issue.

[PHP: How to encode infinity or NaN numbers to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581843/php-how-to-encode-infinity-or-nan-numbers-to-json/13582033#13582033)

Comment: I find it ironic that Google's Gson project says that JSON parsers should allow these literals, while the JavaScript engine that's not tolerating them is Google's own V8.

Comment: @cdhowie node's JSON parser simply follows the spec. The "irony" is just a violation of [the robustness principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)

Comment: @MattBall No, the irony is that one Google project says that *"most JavaScript engines will accept these special values in JSON without problem"* while Google's JavaScript engine is one of the exceptions as evidenced by the fact that Chrome doesn't like the string either.

Comment: "Section 1.2 describes JSON. However, TCP/IP protocol supports many other formats you should be able to decode, given sufficient effort or disregard for security. Therefore, we figured, why restrict ourselves to JSON?" - Google

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Have a node.js app that is receiving JSON data strings that contain the literal NaN, like

Then your NodeJS app **isn't** receiving [JSON](http://json.org), it's receiving text that's vaguely JSON-like. `NaN` is not a valid JSON token.

Three options:

#### 1. Get the source to correctly produce JSON

This is obviously the preferred course. The data is not JSON, that should be fixed, which would fix your problem.

#### 2. Tolerate the `NaN` in a simple-minded way:

You could replace it with `null` before parsing it, e.g.:

```
var result = JSON.parse(yourString.replace(/\bNaN\b/g, "null"));
```

...and then handle `null`s in the result. But that's very simple-minded, it doesn't allow for the possibility that the characters `NaN` might appear in a string somewhere.

Alternately, spinning Matt Ball's `reviver` idea *(now deleted)*, you could change it to a special string (like `"***NaN***"`) and then use a reviver to replace that with the real `NaN`:

```
var result = JSON.parse(yourString.replace(/\bNaN\b/g, '"***NaN***"'), function(key, value) {
    return value === "***NaN***" ? NaN : value;
});
```

...but that has the same issue of being a bit simple-minded, assuming the characters `NaN` never appear in an appropriate place.

#### 3. Use *(shudder!)* `eval`

***If you know and trust the source of this data and there's NO possibility of it being tampered with in transit***, then you could use `eval` to parse it instead of `JSON.parse`. Since `eval` allows full JavaScript syntax, including `NaN`, that works. Hopefully I made the caveat bold enough for people to understand that I would only recommend this in a very, very, *very* tiny percentage of situations. But again, remember `eval` allows arbitrary execution of code, so if there's any possibility of the string having been tampered with, don't use it.

Comment: Assuming that the text "NaN" never occurs in a string. To do this The Right Way(TM) one would need to parse the JSON to determine where the invalid token is -- and at that point you may as well transform the parse tree into an object.  So basically, the right solution is to write your own NaN-tolerant JSON-ish parser.

Comment: Wow!  I was bracing to be shamed for failing to find a well-documented option.  So on the bright side, it looks like that option isn't there to be found.

Comment: @user645715: LOL Indeed not. :-) Glad that helped!

Comment: Very thoughtful replies all.  String replace works for now.  But the datafiles are diverse arbitrary and user-provided, so very well could contain "NaN" in a text column, and the concern over eval() is also valid.  Will see if I can get the library itself changed. Thanks!

Comment: I went with option 3, and it's worth mentioning you need to add parantheses to the input: `function myParseJSON(almost_json) { return eval("(" + almost_json + ")") }`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, as far as I know the problem here is that you can't use `NaN` as a literal JSON value, then why don't just represent it as a string literal `"NaN"` (Note the quotes). Of course this would require some safety checks (if you are expecting integers, you may find that string). Also, it requires to fix the output, but IMHO this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @lordscales91: The problem is the source of the data producing invalid JSON. So #1 suggests fixing it at the source. #2 suggests basically what you suggested in your comment, by pre-processing the string and then post-processing the parsed result.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [JSON5](https://json5.org/) library. A quote from the project page:

> The JSON5 Data Interchange Format (JSON5) is a superset of JSON that aims to alleviate some of the limitations of JSON by expanding its syntax to include some productions from ECMAScript 5.1.
>
> This JavaScript library is the official reference implementation for JSON5 parsing and serialization libraries.

As you would expect, among other things it does support parsing NaNs (compatible with how Python and the like serialize them):

```
JSON5.parse("[1, 2, 3, NaN, 5, 6]")
> (6) [1, 2, 3, NaN, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 7):

When you deal with about anything mathematical or with industry data, `NaN` is terribly convenient (and often infinities too are). And it's an industry standard since IEEE754.

That's obviously why some libraries, notably GSON, let you include them in the JSON they produce, losing standard purity and gaining sanity.

Revival and regex solutions aren't reliably usable in a real project when you exchange complex dynamic objects.

And `eval` has problems too, one of them being the fact it's prone to crash on IE when the JSON string is big, another one being security risks.

That's why I wrote a specific parser (used in production) : [JSON.parseMore](https://github.com/Canop/JSON.parseMore)

Comment: this is great.  Adding parentheses to large strings uses a lot of memory in Node.js as well, and this avoids that.

Comment: "notably GSON, let you include them in the JSON they produce, losing standard purity and gaining sanity" Hallelujah. Thank you so much. It also looks like `jackson` has a `QUOTE_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` parameter. https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.Feature.html

Comment: Steps to reproduce: 1. Get the gson jar and put it where your terminal is looking. 2. `import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class test_gson {
public static void main(String ... args) {
String to_parse = "{\"val\":NaN}";
Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(to_parse, Foo.class);
System.out.println("foo val=" + foo.val + ", is nan=" + foo.val.isNaN());
}
}

class Foo {
public Float val;
}` 3. `javac -cp gson-2.10.1.jar:. test_gson.java` 4. `java -cp gson-2.10.1.jar:. test_gson` -> `foo val=NaN, is nan=true`

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to recompile the parser, and contribute an "allowNan"  boolean flag to the source base.  This is the solution other libraries have (python's comes to mind).

Good JSON libraries will permissively parse just about anything vaguely resembling JSON with the right flags set (perl's JSON.pm is notably flexible)... but when writing a message they produce standard JSON.

IE:  leave the room cleaner than you found it.

Answer (score -1):

Just a minor addition to TJ Crowder's already comprehensive enough reply, I'd rather use

```
var result = JSON.parse(yourString.replace(/\bNaN\b/g, '"NaN"'));
```

because I actually need to know if its a NaN value.

Also I'd do this inside a fetch or axios GET request, only if the default JSON parsing failed and the data came as a string.

```
const StringConstructor = "".constructor;

if (data.constructor === StringConstructor) {
    data = JSON.parse(tableData.data.replace(/\bNaN\b/g, '"NaN"'))
}
```

Comment: This will further corrupt your JSON if you have any other "NaN" substrings inside other strings.