# Javascript JSON.parse: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I have JSON data generated in Python using Flask's `jsonify` method.

When I try to parse it in Google Chrome by doing

```
JSON.parse(s)
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N
```

I can't post the json since it is proprietary and gigantic.
Why would I be getting this error if the JSON is generated by a well tested method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this tool to discover the problem:
https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint

The problem was due to Flask's jsonify allowing the serialization of NaN, but Google Chrome's implementation following the JSON spec and not allowing NaN.

Some workarounds are listed here:
[How to parse JSON string containing "NaN" in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228651/how-to-parse-json-string-containing-nan-in-node-js)