# python numeric string comparison

Tags: python, string, types, comparison

I have numerical values that are loaded from a `JSON` object and are therefore all strings.

I am having issues with making numerical comparisons with these strings. The following makes no sense to me and I was hoping one of you champions could explain..

```
In[2]: print '100' < '45'
True

In[3]: print '99' < '45'
False
```

Using `Python 2.7`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When comparing strings they're compared by the ascii value of the characters.  `'1'` has a value 49, and `'4'` is 52.  So `'1'` is < `'4'`.  `'9'` however is 57, so `'9'` is > '`4'`.

If you want to compare them numerically you could just `int()` the strings first like:

```
print int('100') < int('45')
```

Comment: I ended up converting all the values in the dictionary to `float`, although I had to account for `nan` with an if loop because the `JSON` parser on the client side (Chrome) was throwing an error with `NaN`, I had to replace `NaN` with `None` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228651/how-to-parse-json-string-containing-nan-in-node-js)

Answer (score 4):

It basically checks for lexicographic ordering. 
Check documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) -

```
>>> 'b' <'a'
False
>>> 'a' < 'b'
True
```

In above example, a comes before b, hence `'a' <'b'` is true. But, not vica versa. Similarly `'1'<'2'`.
Hence `'199999999999' < '5'`  is true because  1 comes before 5.

Comment: Have u verified your claim - '599999999999' < '1' is true

Comment: my bad I meant something like this `'1999' < '5'`. edited in the answer. Thanks @AlokThakur

Comment: The document link you provide is so much helpful to me.