# d3.json cannot parse an 'Infinity' value

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to read sqlite db data and provide it as json data to d3 to build a graph. I can easily read this data in json format, for example this URL

http://localhost:8085/SQLQuery/?date1=2019-03-01%2000:00:00&date2=2019-03-31%2023:59:59&radio=0013a200410a4bc1

Returns this data:

```
[
   ["2019-03-13 08:59:42.445199", 20.0, -93150.3125, -1128635.625],
   ["2019-03-13 09:00:18.670074", 21.0, -116238.2734375, -Infinity],
   ["2019-03-13 09:00:54.897829", 21.0, -111895.09375, -1916368.5],
   ["2019-03-13 09:01:31.063545", 21.0, -116290.6484375, -1332886.0],
   ["2019-03-13 09:02:07.244134", 21.0, -99264.3828125, -Infinity],
   ["2019-03-13 09:02:43.424961", 21.0, -109359.6953125, -1090349.25],
   ["2019-03-13 09:03:19.621574", 21.0, -114976.4375, -3437984.0],
   ["2019-03-13 09:03:55.800267", 21.0, -97664.5078125, -1667308.5],
   ["2019-03-13 09:04:31.995798", 21.0, -102451.046875, -Infinity],
   ["2019-03-13 09:05:08.172229", 21.0, -109326.34375, -3360548.75],
   ["2019-03-13 09:05:44.367397", 21.0, -110630.9140625, -732758.8125],
   ["2019-03-13 09:06:20.576101", 21.0, -110025.140625, -926976.3125],
   ["2019-03-13 09:06:56.771144", 21.0, -116129.8984375, -Infinity]
]
```

Now when using d3.json function to read the same data I've problems with 'Infinity' values:

```
jsondata = d3.json("http://localhost:8085/SQLQuery/?date1=" + date1 + "&date2=" + date2 + "&radio=" + wradio);
```

gives error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-digit at line 1 column 122 of the JSON data

> Column 122 corresponds to first 'Infinity' value in json data.

Is there any option to allow the parsing of 'Infinity' values ? Do I need to ensure that these values never arrive to database and are converted to valid numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228712/5768908) (your question is not a duplicate, though) your best option is producing the correct JSON, which you can pass to `d3.json`.

However, if that's not an option, you can use `d3.text` to fetch the invalid JSON, like this (assuming you're using D3 v5):

```
d3.text("data.json").then(function(textData){
    //...
};
```

And then, inside `d3.text` (or the `then` method in v5), you can replace the `-Infinity` for a corresponding string, before using `JSON.parse()`:

```
textData = textData.replace(/-Infinity/g, '"-Infinity"');
const data = JSON.parse(textData);
```

Also, following the advice in the same linked answer, you can restore the original `-Infinity`, replacing the string by using the reviver function in the `JSON.parse()`:

```
textData = textData.replace(/-Infinity/g, '"-Infinity"');
const data = JSON.parse(textData, function(key, value){
    return value === "-Infinity" ? -Infinity : value;
});
```

Since I cannot use a real JSON in the stack snippet, here is a blockbuilder, using a JSON like yours:

```
[
    ["2019-03-13 08:59:42.445199", 20.0, -93150.3125, -1128635.625],
    ["2019-03-13 09:00:18.670074", 21.0, -116238.2734375, -Infinity],
    ["2019-03-13 09:00:54.897829", 21.0, -111895.09375, -1916368.5]
]
```

Have a look at the console: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/e853f11e0604a929f82fcd62a33f925e

Comment: It works ! it will provide a robust option to parse NaN values. The other alternative is to ensure these values never arrive to database but by far not a clever solution. Thanks.