# jQuery $.get response is different when Infinity is in the response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an API that returns two numbers as a response. For example if I call this

```
$.get('/api/get_limit/').always(function(data) { console.log(data.responseText); });
```

I expect to see something like this in the console

```
Object {absolute_limit: 389, concurrent_limit: 999}
```

Which is what I get, except when one of these numbers is Infinity. In that case when I make the same request, the console will show

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"absolute_limit":Infinity,"concurrent_limit":999.0}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

I checked and API is working as expected in both cases.

My question is why this happens and is there a way I can fix this **without** substituting Infinity with something like -1?

EDIT:

Django code for generating API with the help of Django Rest Framework

```
class QueriesLimit(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        limit = request.user.concurrency_limit()
        abs_limit = request.user.available_queries()
        return Response({'concurrent_limit': limit, 'absolute_limit': abs_limit})
```

Comment: Can you add the API code that generates the JSON?

Comment: Why you're using `$.get()` when the return value is (should be) JSON? [PHP: How to encode infinity or NaN numbers to JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581843/php-how-to-encode-infinity-or-nan-numbers-to-json)

Comment: Do not attempt to encode JSON manually - you should use an available library to encode your dictionaries/arrays to JSON. Not being terribly familiar with python, this looks like what you should be using: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: @Adam I am not encoding it manually. I pass it Python object and the APIView class will take care of encoding. The problem seems to be in Infinity not being a valid JSON value

Comment: @zanderle - if it was encoding it properly, then it would encode `Infinity` as `"Infinity"` because JSON strings need to be double-quoted. So it's obviously not encoding it properly.

Comment: @Adam the problem was elsewhere. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#infinite-and-nan-number-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cause

```
{
    "absolute_limit": Infinity,
                      ^^^^^^^^
    "concurrent_limit": 999.0
}
```

is not a json object

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. How would you pass Infinity then?

Comment: maybe replace the Infinity value with a `special value`